# How to resize google recaptcha challenge image

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, grecaptcha

This is my code for recaptcha
`<div  class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="${siteKey}" data-callback="call1" data-expired-callback="call2">`

I am not able to resize the challenge popup.

[image]

my login code is inside the iframe. but I want to take out the challenge popup, as it has horizontal and vertical scrollbars.

Unable to resize the popup. Need to get rid of scrollbars for this challenge popup and show the full image

Comment: What are users supposed to sign into there? If this is something external, then iframing it is probably not a good idea to begin with.

Comment: We cant get rid of the iframe. Its coming from another party

Comment: So this is a login _to_ another website? Even more reason then, to **not** do this in an iframe. Because by doing that, you would be educating users that it was fine to enter their credentials on 3rd-party websites, with no way of controlling where their data will be sent via the browser address bar. Giving users that _wrong_ impression, would make a you contributor to the problem called _phishing_.

Comment: We can trust the party. Can not get rid of it. If you know the solution how to resize it please share

Comment: _"We can trust the party."_ - whether you trust them, is absolutely not the point. If _they_ are okay with you showing their login mask in an iframe, then they are part of the problem. _"If you know the solution how to resize it please share"_ - other than trying to apply a `scale` transformation, there is probably not much you can do.

Comment: Bizarre to begin with, that the login functionality would be under their control, but then the captcha gets added by you on your end.

Comment: Scale transformation only resizes the initial captcha box, not the challenge/puzzle which we get after checking the box

Comment: If you apply the transformation on the `.g-recaptcha` element that will _contain_ the iframe that will render the captcha, then I don't see how it could _not_ scale everything. (But again, this is all sounds so _terribly_ wrong already to begin with ...)

Comment: Applying transformation to .g-recaptcha, resizes the initial captcha box as well which I dont want, I want that captcha box width 100% of the main container.

Comment: I can't get the "puzzle" to trigger with any live examples right now, so I can't go check what the DOM will look like. Inspect it yourself, perhaps you'll find something inside of the container, that _can_ be accessed individually (like, maybe the puzzle renders in a second iframe, that was somehow identifiable.)